# We get error when we try to connect and read from sql db and store to sql db

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

We use Azure data factory and Integration runtime.
So if we use a single copy activity in a pipeline and the source is a SQL db and target is a SQL db we get this error marked with * below.
Here is a print where I use a single copy activity which doesn't work

[image]

Here is the error message.

> (*)ErrorCode=SqlFailedToConnect,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Cannot connect to SQL Database. Please contact SQL server team for further support. Server: 'qbim.database.windows.net', Database: 'Hemavan', User: 'Daniel'. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.),Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=121,Class=20,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=0,Errors=[{Class=20,Number=121,State=0,Message=A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.),},],''Type=System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Message=The semaphore timeout period has expired,Source=,'

But if we instead use two copy activity in this way.
The first copy actity source read the SQL db and the target in the first copy activity write to a blobstorage and the source in the second activity read the blob storage and target in the second activity write the SQL db it works just fine.
It works if we have it like this

[image]

The sad thing is that we can't use the blobstorage functionality for a long time because we run this piperline 10 times each day and that cost far to much.
We must use a single activity to minimize cost where we first read from SQL db and then write to SQL db in the target.

The strange thing is that we have used the configuration with a single activity in a pipeline which works just fine where we read the SQL db in the source and in the target we write to the sqldb.

If we look at the error we can see that it also says

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake.

It must be something wrong with the configuration in the SQL Server where the source is located.

It is indeed very strange that it works when I first write to a blob storage and then in the second activity write to a SQL db.

Note I use Self hosted integration runtime and the source database is on premise.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Self hosted integration runtime

Comment: Are you copying data from on premises sql database to azure sql database?

Comment: `find a good solution by using chatGPT but haven't find any good solution.` a statistical text generator's answers depend on how good the question is. Despite its length, this question doesn't even explain where the data comes from, or what database throws the error. If you google the error `A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake` you'll  find a lot of similar questions and solutions.

Comment: The inner error `The semaphore timeout period has expired.` is a network problem. This says there was a timeout while trying to establish the connection. Where are you connecting to?

Answer (score 0):

```
Cannot connect to SQL Database. Please contact SQL server team for further support. Server: '****.database.windows.net', Database: '****', User: '***'. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.
```

The error above is related to the firewall rule. When trying to copy data from blob storage to Azure SQL Database, if both are in the same client, you might not encounter access-related errors. However, when copying data from on-premises to Azure SQL Database, the client may be different. To resolve this, add the client IP address to the SQL server as follows:

Go to Azure SQL Server Networking, click on Add Client IP Address, and save it as shown below:

[image]

Afterward, use only the copy activity to copy data from the on-premises database to Azure SQL Database using the SQL database. It will run successfully without any error, as shown below:

[image]